# Why Gröbner basis is complete

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm reading a paper about Gröbner basis. Suppose $P$ is a set of multivariate polynomials in $n$ variables and $V(P)$ is the set of all the points $\alpha$ such that for every polynomial in $P$ like $q$, $q(\alpha )=0$, it means $V(P)$ is affine variety of $P$ and we define $I(V(P))$ be the set of all polynomials such that they are zero on whole $V(P)$. It is said that if $P$ is a Gröbner basis then $\left<P\right>=I(V(P))$ but I don't understand why $I(V(P))\subset \left <P\right>$. Could you please give me a hint?

Here $\left <P\right >$ is the ideal generated by $P$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general unless you are working over an algebraically closed field. In that case, the result you need is **Hilbert's Nullstellensatz**.

For example, if you were working over the field of real numbers, the polynomial $f(T)=T^{2}+1$ does not have any roots, so its vanishing locus is empty. But the polynomial constantly equal to 1 vanishes on every point of $V(f)$. Hence $1\in I(V(f))$, so we get that $I(V(f))=\mathbb{R}[T] \nsubseteq (T^{2}+1)$.

Comment: Yes you are right thank you. But if we work on algebraically closed field then the proof is easy?

Comment: It is not true even for algebraically closed fields. Take $P=\{x^2\}$. Then $V(P)=\{0\}$ so $I(V(P))=(x)$ not $(x^2)$.

Comment: Even if you are working on algebraically closed fields, you only get that the ideal of the vanishing locus of the family is the radical of the ideal generated by the family of polynomials. Otherwise you get examples like the one just mentioned by @Levent

Comment: By the way, the question is irrelevant of $P$ being a Gröbner basis.

Comment: @Nothing and no, I would not call any of the proofs of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz I've seen "easy". But that depends on your usage of the word easy and on how smart you are I guess.

Comment: @Levent  Yes guys you are both right. But it is a thesis of Berkeley:) So they are wrong.

Comment: @Nothing which thesis is that? Do you mean it is a thesis of a grad student in UC Berkeley or a mathematician with name Berkeley?

Comment: @Levent it is a thesis of a grad student in UC Berkeley. A PhD student!!

Comment: @Nothing Well, I am not the one reading it but I will not exclude the possibility that you are missing some hypothesis in the text :)

Comment: @Levent I think so:) I should study it again and give advice of my supervisor tomorrow. Thanks.